# What are the contraints and usecases in SvelteKit for +page.ts, +page.server.ts, and +server.ts?

Tags: sveltekit

When using `Sveltekit`, it seems that there are some blurred lines between the 3 types of files `+page.ts`, `page.server.ts`, and `server.ts`.

- What are the constraints on what can go into each file? (eg. can +page.server.ts respond to form requests from pages outside its route?)
- Which type of file can provide what type of functionality and what can it not?
- What overlaps can exist between the files? (eg. can both +page.server.ts and +server.ts provide a POST method end point?)
- What does the presence of one type of file exclude on another? (eg. if there is a +page.server.ts can there also be a +page.ts or a +server.ts?)
- Can the `formactions` of +page.server.ts be an endpoint for another route that calls it?

Any other relevant points for understanding the placement of these files and their roles would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Most of your questions are already answered in the official documentation:

> What are the constraints on what can go into each file? (eg. can +page.server.ts respond to form requests from pages outside its route?)

Take a look at [universal vs server](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#universal-vs-server) section in the documentation. You will get an idea of what goes where. As per your second question in here, yes, any `+page.server.ts` can respond to form requests from any other page (including itself). As a matter of fact, I'm currently working on a project where I'm using this exact feature.

> Which type of file can provide what type of functionality and what can it not?

Again, a look at the [universal vs server](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#universal-vs-server) should clarify this point.

> What overlaps can exist between the files? (eg. can both +page.server.ts and +server.ts provide a POST method end point?)

This in particular is explained in the [server content negotiation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server-content-negotiation) section.

> What does the presence of one type of file exclude on another? (eg. if there is a +page.server.ts can there also be a +page.ts or a +server.ts?)

They are not exclusive but complementary. You can have a server only load function in `+page.server.ts` and a client one in `+page.ts` which will run on the server or the client depending on the SSR/CSR conditions. It could even grab the data generated in your `+page.server.ts` file and augment it with other stuff, for example. Finally, you could also have a `+server.ts` providing API functionality to your pages.

> Can the formactions of +page.server.ts be an endpoint for another route that calls it?

I'm not sure I understand your question but the form actions act as a way to submit forms. Granted it has it's own format for proper communication of statues but nothing stops you from injecting the data you need too. Perhaps, I'd keeps forms and APIs separate unless there is a good reason but nothing prevents you from mixing them (for both scenarios, as form submissions and as regular API endpoints).